# solution for reccurence relation, different solution than wolframalpha

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

I have reccurence relation:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{1-p}a_{n-1}-\frac{p}{1-p}a_{n-2}$$

Solving this using method from wikipedia, so plug $a_n=r^n$

$$r^2-\frac{1}{1-p}r+\frac{p}{1-p}$$

so $r_1=\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}-\lvert\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\rvert}{2}$ and $r_2=\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}+\lvert\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\rvert}{2}$ (if I calculated this correctly)

So the general solution should be

$$A(\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}-\lvert\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\rvert}{2})^n+B(\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}+\lvert\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\rvert}{2})^n$$

But [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a_n%3D%281%2F%281-p%29%29a_%7Bn-1%7D-p%2F%281-p%29a_%7Bn-2%7D) says:

$$A(\frac{p}{1-p})^n+B$$

What is correct?

Comment: You should have re-written $r^2-\frac{1}{1-p}r+\frac{p}{1-p}=\color{red}{0}$ into the equivalent quadratic : $(1-p)r^2-r+p=0$ : in this way you would have had a much simpler expression... and made the connection with WA expression.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between your solution and that of Wolfram Alpha. If $\frac{1-2p}{1-p} \ge 0$ then
$$
r_1=\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1-2p}{1-p}}{2} = \frac{p}{1-p} \\
r_2=\frac{\frac{1}{1-p}+\frac{1-2p}{1-p}}{2} = 1
$$
and if $\frac{1-2p}{1-p} < 0$ then $r_1 = 1$, $r_2 = \frac{p}{1-p}$.

In other words:  The set
$$ 
\{ r_1, r_2 \} = \left\{ \frac 12 \left( \frac{1}{1-p}-\left|\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\right|\right) ,
\frac 12 \left( \frac{1}{1-p}+\left|\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\right|\right) \right\}
$$
is equal to the set
$$
\left\{ \frac 12 \left( \frac{1}{1-p}-\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\right) ,
\frac 12 \left( \frac{1}{1-p}+\frac{1-2p}{1-p}\right) \right\}
= \{ \frac{p}{1-p}, 1 \} 
$$
so you just “found” a slightly more complicated way to describe the solution set of
$$
r^2-\frac{1}{1-p}r+\frac{p}{1-p} = \bigl(r-1\bigr) \left( r-\frac{p}{1-p}\right)
$$